# What is the fastest and shortest way to double (or multiply) a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

If you have a vector like this one, what is the shortest way to double or multiply it?

```
vector<pair<int, string>> v = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}};
vector<pair<int, string>> desired_v = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}};
```

Of course these version won't work:

```
v1.insert(v1.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end());
// {{1, "a"}{2, "b"}{3, "c"}{1, ""}{2, ""}{3, ""}}

for (auto p : v2)
    v2.push_back(p);
// {{1, "a"}{2, "b"}{3, "c"}{1, "a"}{2, ""}{3, ""}}
```

Of course I can use this one, but it is pretty lame:

```
for (size_t curr = 0, size = v3.size(); curr < size; ++curr)
    v3.push_back(v3.at(curr));
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Create a new one from `v`, and then insert the `v` again?

Comment: @NathanOliver: wow I thought I had got the dupe hammer for a moment :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just loaned it to you :-)

Comment: just missing 750 upvotes :)